# docker not found with docker:dind + google/cloud-sdk

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, google-cloud-sdk

I'm getting the error `docker: command not found` while running the following CI script inside gitlab-ci. This error is happening during `before_script` for the deploy phase.

```
services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

before_script:
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY

build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:latest
  script:
    - docker info
    - docker version
    - docker build --pull -t $SERVICE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME .
    - docker image list
    - docker tag $SERVICE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$SERVICE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$SERVICE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

test:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$SERVICE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - docker image list
    - docker run $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$SERVICE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME npm test

deploy:
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  stage: deploy
  environment: Production
  script:
    - echo $DEPLOY_KEY_FILE_PRODUCTION > /tmp/GCLOUD_KEYFILE.json
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/GCLOUD_KEYFILE.json
    - rm /tmp/GCLOUD_KEYFILE.json
    - gcloud info
    - gcloud components list
  only:
    - master
```

I'm a bit confused, because I'm runing docker-in-docker (`docker:dind`) as a service so the docker command should be made available to all stages (if I understand this correctly), however it's clearly not.

Is it due to an interaction with google/cloud-sdk ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably misunderstood what `services` mean. From the [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#what-is-a-service),

> The services keyword defines just another docker image that is run during your job and is linked to the docker image that the image keyword defines.

What you need is a custom docker executor that uses dind image and preinstalled with gcloud sdk. You can build such an image with this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM docker:latest

RUN apk add --no-cache \
 bash \
 build-base \
 curl \
 git \
 libffi-dev \
 openssh \
 openssl-dev \
 python \
 py-pip \
 python-dev

RUN pip install docker-compose fabric
RUN curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash -s -- --disable-prompts
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I believe you're right. But it's a bit counterintuitive. Gitlab provided in their docs the example of running mysql as a service. This way, `mysql` can be called in any stage of a build. So with the same logic, I should be able to run Docker in docker as a service, and access the docker command in any stage. But it's not the case.

Comment: To add to the ambiguity, all people using `dind` in a service are also using the [`docker:latest` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/), which is already Docker in Docker ! WTF. Is there something really obvious I'm missing here ?

Comment: I'll upvote for now and wait to see if I can get more feedback, i'll try your approach asap

Comment: It's the *context*. 

`services` specifies the services your app image will link to during build stage so you can, for example, run tests.

What you really want is to run gcloud in the context of the gitlab runner that builds your image.

Comment: So services are for running containers in the "background", like databases for instance. `docker:dind` is the docker daemon that needs to run in the background, while `docker:latest` is a container with the docker CLI (among other things), that is calling `docker:dind` in the background. Both are required. Is this correct ?

Comment: Your `before_script` `docker login` runs by an executor. If your executor executes in a context where `docker` cli is not installed, it fails. So you need a docker executor where `docker` is installed. This is usually solved with dind. Now, when building your app inside dind, you might want to run  some tests, and if it needs a db, you specify the db image with `services`.

Comment: Ok, get it. Thanks, it's much clearer now. And my CI pipeline passes now  :)

Comment: Damn I still don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked almost 5 years ago, I am unsure if by that time the image `google/cloud-sdk` shipped without docker binaries, I can't think of anything else for a `docker: command not found` error more than it was not available in the standard location. Anyways, today 2022 `google/cloud-sdk` comes with docker and it can interact with the docker service, and since I ended up here several times after running into problems trying to use `docker:dind` and `google/cloud-sdk`, I will add the following:

Is possible to use docker from the `google/cloud-sdk` image, there is no need to create a custom image for your Gitlab CI. The problem is that docker in `google/cloud-sdk` tries to connect to the socket in `/var/run/docker.sock` as is presented in the logs:

```sh
$ docker build -t gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/test:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA .
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Anyways you can also checks in your logs of the service `docker:dind` that docker listens in a socket (not reachable from the job container) and a tcp port (reachable via the hostname `docker`). So, you just need to use the tcp port in your docker commands, either by setting the env variable `DOCKER_HOST` or adding a `-H tcp://docker:2375` as in

```sh
$ docker -H tcp://docker:2375 build -t gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/test:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA .
Step 1/8 : FROM python:latest
```